# XSLT Transforming repeating elements into one while maintaining order

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform some XML using a stylesheet that starts out looking like:

```
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000000</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
```

Into this:

```
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>9</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>9</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>0</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
```

I am not too strong in xslt so this may be a basic but everything I have tried so far is coming back with:

```
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>9</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>9</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>0</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
```

Any suggestions would really be appreciated...

Thank You in advance

Comment: Please see my answer. Could you please accept the best answers. Click on the check mark next to the answer that you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you posted are not valid Xml documents - the one you want to transform has multiple root elements and neither shows what namespace m10 prefix is bound to.

You can use identity transform to achieve what you want. I kind of fixed your input document so that it was possible to write an xslt. My input document looks like this:

```
<root xmlns:m10="m10">
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>  
        <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>  
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>  
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>  
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>  
        <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>  
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>  
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>  
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>  
        <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>  
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000000</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>  
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>  
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
</root>
```

I created the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:m10="m10">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms your input document to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL xmlns:m10="m10" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
     <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO><m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT><m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX><m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>  
     <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO><m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT><m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX><m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>  
     <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO><m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT><m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000000</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX><m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG>
</m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:m10="m10">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL/*" /> 
  </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform this input document

```
<root xmlns:m10="m10" > 
<m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>001</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>002</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000109</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000009</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
     </m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
     <m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL> 
        <m10:LINE_NO>003</m10:LINE_NO> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT>00000100</m10:APPR_ITEM_AMT> 
        <m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX>00000000</m10:APPR_ITEM_TAX> 
        <m10:TAX_FLAG>N</m10:TAX_FLAG> 
</m10:RESPONSE_DETAIL>
</root>
```

as required.